# What is Event Notification Delivery Method in the eBay SDK and what am I supposed to do with it

Tags: python, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I am trying to use the eBay python SDK and APIs for finding listings (Finding API) and I need to make a production Key. However, when you create a production key you get the message

> **"Your Keyset is currently disabled**

> **Comply with marketplace deletion/account closure notification process
> or apply for an exemption"**

I'm not really sure what this means and the guide I was following makes no mention of it (because it was required after the guide was made). What do I put for the Email field and the https address etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all instructions [here](https://developer.ebay.com/marketplace-account-deletion#:%7E:text=Sign%20into%20your%20developer%20account,to%20the%20Application%20Keys%20page.&text=On%20the%20Alerts%20and%20Notifications,Event%20Notification%20Delivery%20Method%20section.)